How do I identify the first-class and second-class constraints of a given Lagrangian?
I've been in correspondence with a potential PhD advisor who wants me to solve a problem wherein I need to find the first-class and second-class constraints for a given Lagrangian. I'm having some difficulty with this, and while I don't want anyone to solve this for me (that would be unethical), I'd like to ask for some guidance in solving this.
$$\mathcal{L}_{\text {ZDG}}=\left(-\sigma M_1 e_{1 a} R_1^a-\frac{1}{6} m^2 M_1 \alpha_1 \varepsilon_{a b c} e_1^a e_1^b e_1^c\right)+\left(-M_2 e_{2 a} R_2^a-\frac{1}{6} m^2 M_2 \alpha_2 \varepsilon_{a b c} e_2^a e_2^b e_2^c\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2} m^2 \frac{\sigma M_1 M_2}{\sigma M_1 M_2} \varepsilon_{a b c}\left(\beta_1 e_1^a e_1^b e_2^c+\beta_2 e_1^a e_2^b e_2^c\right)\right)$$
The Lagrangian is eqs. (3)-(5) from this paper.
and I know there are 6 first-class constraints and 8 second-class constraints.

I've read through parts of Blagojeciv, which provides an example starting on p141 with:
$$\mathcal{\widetilde{L}}=ba(AT_{ijk}T^{ijk}+BT_{ijk}T^{ijk}+CT_{k}T^{k})+\lambda_{ij}^{\mu\nu}R^{ij}_{\mu\nu}+\mathcal{\widetilde{L}}_{M}$$
In their example, they identify the primary and secondary constraints, and then identify each as first-class or second-class.
I partially understand their procedure, but not sufficiently to duplicate their results myself (let alone apply that knowledge to a different Lagrangian).

Again, I do NOT want the answers to simply be handed to me. This is about understanding how to get the answers myself. I feel like I've exhausted the resources I've been able to find on my own, and I need help.

Why don't you ask the "potential PhD advisor" this question?

They're busy with various conferences they're currently attending, so tend to take about a week to actually respond to emails. I did ask them one question to clarify that I was understanding the question right though.

Sounds like someone who will be too busy to be an good advisor. Maybe this is their way of telling you.

No, this is just an unusually busy period for them. I honestly can't be picky anyway - my CV isn't exactly strong. I just need a bit of help with this problem.
